# Counting occurrences of random variable in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of N names, let's say:

`Albert
Barbara
Catherine
Daniel
Edward
Frank
...`

Then I have a set of M cells, M < N. These M cells are filled randomly with names from the list. As it is random (the RAND() function is somewhere in the formula), if I press Delete on an empty cell, the set of M names changes.

What I want is to determine the probability of a specific name being in the final set.

I know how to check if the name is there, but I don't know how to count how many times, over time, it is there.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: @pnuts you're suggesting I copy every value A1 and B1 return and the average it? I was thinking in about 100.000 values...

Comment: I've reformulated the problem. Take a look, please.

Answer (score 2):

This approach uses **A4** to count *zero* results and **A5** to count *one* results.  Put the following *Event Macro* in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Range("A2").Value = 0 Then
        Range("A4").Value = Range("A4").Value + 1
    Else
        Range("A5").Value = Range("A5").Value + 1
    End If

    Range("A3").Value = Range("A5").Value / (Range("A4").Value + Range("A5").Value)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you! Well I guessed it could only be done with macros, but I never studied macros and that's why I asked this question.
As soon as I test it, I'll give you feedback and thank you again :)

Comment: @MarcoCastanho  We call this type of application a *Monti Carlo* analysis.

Comment: btw, I may want to reset the counters sometime. How can I do that? Disable the macro and enable it again?